# Can my partner travel to Hungary alone with an EU/EEA family member visa

Tags: customs-and-immigration, hungarian-citizens

I'm travelling home to Hungary and my partner can't come with me on the same day due to work, but he can after a couple of days. He has an EU/EEA family member visa so I'm wondering if he will be allowed to travel without me. We did a couple of years ago and he was let through because I was present and traveling with him.

Can this be possible please?

Comment: Is it a card or a sticker in the passport? Please upload a copy of the "visa" blacking oiut personal details. In general though, he can travel to join you

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Freedom of movement rights for non-EU family of EU, EEA, or Swiss citizens apply if the family members travel together or if the non-EU family member is traveling to join the EU family member.

You and your partner should be prepared to demonstrate that you are in Hungary in case passport control officers ask for proof.

Comment: Yeah we will waiting for him at the airport and if anything there, they can just find me outside. I hope they let him go from UK as well without any trouble. We have 2 kids so should be ok.

Comment: @Petcsi what do you mean "you hope they let him go from UK without any trouble"?  Is he in the UK now?  Why would he have trouble on leaving the UK?

Comment: It's not "trouble" I mean. Just 2 years a go they was holding us up for checking proper everything. And in the back way too. So I thought it will more difficult for him alone. But it's fine I called the my embassy and they said just make sure he have the copy of the kids birthcetificate ,plus copy of my passport. I told them I will also waiting for him at the airport. So that should be fine.